# thyratrons or vacuum tubes for relay control

Tags: relay, vacuum-tube

I am trying to build a tube amp without using any semiconductors (just for the fun of it, trying to make it using the technology that was available when tube amps were mainstream). I may need to control some relays in it, however, I cannot figure out how, or rather, how to do it properly.

I have some thyratrons (both hot and cold cathode) and obviously some vacuum tubes. 
I may have to:

1. turn a relay on or off with a pulse (like a push button)
2. Switch between two relays (one off one on)
3. have a relay turn on for some time then turn off (shorting the output of the amp for a few seonds to avoid a pop when switching inputs etc).

How do I do it without semiconductors? I currently do not have a specific application in mind, just looking to learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To 1st and 2nd problem you need a simple flip-flop. You can make it from two triodes or one dual triode. Look at this schematic from [DRTE Computer](http://www.friendsofcrc.ca/Projects/DRTEComputer/TheDRTEComputer-p2.html) site:

[image]

Outputs are on anodes of tubes. One output have high level and other have a low level, trigger pulse swap levels of outputs. There are many vacuum-tube flip-flops like this one, similar in construction, and all of them have its origin in first ever know digital circuit: [Eccles-Jordan flip-flop](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=GB&NR=148582&KC=&FT=E).

Solution to the 3rd problem is single-shot multivibrator:

[image]

Output is on the A2 anode. Values of R and C connected to A1 anode gives You a time of output pulse duration. This circuit comes from P.Neeteson book ["Vacuum valves in pulse technique"](http://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/046/suppinfo/Philips_ElectronicValves_BookIX_1959.pdf), page 117. Another circuit You may found here: http://mysite.du.edu/~etuttle/electron/elect36.htm

There are also other solution to control relays without transistors and also without tubes - You may use only relays. But I suppose that it will be hard to find old "non-electronic" (fully electro-mechanical) pulse-trigerred and time delay relays - eBay and flea-markets should be Your friends.

Comment: Completely forgot about flip-flops. I guess when I am thinking about tubes I am not thinking about digital circuits.